# Unable to get list of all files using google drive API

Tags: java, list, google-drive-api

I am currently integrating goggle drive with my Java web application and I have an issue while getting the list of files associated with a account. I am using
https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?key={API-key} to get the list of files, but I am only getting the folders and files which are created from with in my application I am not able to get all the folders for that particular account.

For the same account when I tested it through 'try it' on 'developers.google.com' I am able to get all the folders and files

I am not able to understand why I am not getting all folders when I make the call from my application, should I be request for any extra permissions from google? Please help me what should I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior occurs when you only select the drive.files scope, which will only list the items created and/or modified by the application. You will need all of the listed scopes in this document (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) in order to access all the files from your drive account. Be sure to add all the scopes under your project, at https://console.developers.google.com

Comment: Hi @Rivero changing the scope worked for me. Thank you